# Why are certain Books Excluded from the Canon?

Tags: bible, canon

I trust the current Biblical canon, but I was researching Biblical evidence against Purgatory when I came across a Catholic blog that used the book of II Maccabees as evidence. That got me thinking: why have the books in the canon been chosen? Any insight on this subject will be helpful, thanks.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by your question `Why are certain Books Excluded from the Cannon?`. Who are you talking about? Protestant reformers who excluded deuterocanonical books from OT or the participants in the Councils of Carthage/Council of Rome who excluded many books in the NT?

Comment: I am not well versed in this topic but I believe my question pertains to the participants in the Councils of Carthage/Council of Rome who excluded many books in the NT. I am trying to figure why the Catholics have more books and why the difference?

Comment: (Just a note: the word you wanted was [canon](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/canon?r=75&src=ref&ch=dic); a cannon fires cannonballs with gunpowder.)

Comment: @TommyR: That is exactly the problem. If your question is `Why Catholics have more books?` then you should probably ask about Protestant reformers as they were the one who removed books later on. For that please see: [Why were Deuterocanonical books rejected in the Reformation?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3189/why-were-deuterocanonical-books-rejected-in-the-reformation)

Comment: The Wikipedia page "Biblical Canon" <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_of_Scripture> has a good overview of the subject.

Comment: Also related: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/12567/are-there-books-that-are-included-in-the-protestant-bible-that-were-disputed-as